# Type 'Bluebird<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, promise, sequelize.js, syntax-error

When i try to do a syntax like this, i get this error and i don't know why, this only happens in vscode, has someone solved this?

```
const [errorDB, responseDB]: any = await awaitToJs(db.Order.findAll({
    attributes: ['purchaseOrderNum'],
    where: {
      purchaseOrderNum: { [db.Op.or]: shopIds },
    },
  }));
```

Argument of type 'import(".../node_modules/sequelize/types/lib/promise") is not assignable to parameter of type. The types returned by 'then(...)' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'Bluebird' is not assignable to type 'Promise'

Comment: What's `awaitToJs`?

Comment: Is a function from our node_modules

`export declare function to<T, U = Error>(promise: Promise<T>, errorExt?: object): Promise<[U | null, T | undefined]>;`
`export default to;`

Comment: Just guessing here, but up to v6 Sequelize uses Bluebird insted of native promises. So I guess `findAll()` is returning a `Bluebird` type while `awaitToJs` is expecting a param of type `Promise`. Not sure what's the purpose of `awaitToJs`, but if you need that function the only options I see are: (1) try and cast to `Promise` or (2) upgrade Sequelize to v6.